# Show that $S$ is a subbasis for the topology $\mathcal T$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be a topological space where $X = \{ a,b,c,d,e,f \}$ and $\mathcal T = \{\emptyset, X , \{a \}, \{c,d \}, \{a,c,d\}, \{b,c,d,e,f\}\}$.
>
> Show that $S = \{\{a\}, \{a,c,d\}, \{b,c,d,e,f\} \}$ forms a subbasis for the topology $\mathcal T$ on $X$.

I know that $S$ is a subbasis for the topology $\mathcal T$ on $X$ if the collection of all finite intersections of $S$ forms a basis for $\mathcal T$.

So I found all the finite intersections of $S$ as follows:

\begin{align}\{a\}\cap \{a,c,d\}&= \{a\} \\ \{a\} \cap \{b,c,d,e,f\} &= \emptyset \\
\{a,c,d\} \cap \{ b,c,d,e,f\} &= \{c,d\} \end{align}

So, essentially, if I have this correct, I need to show that the set $$\mathcal B = \{ \emptyset, \{a\}, \{c,d\} \}$$ forms a basis for $\mathcal T$. Correct?

I cannot seem to see how this is a basis for $\mathcal T$ though?

Comment: This is not a basis for $\mathbb{T}$. It is clear to see. There should be something wrong with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are also allowed intersections of one or zero elements, so you need to show that
$$
\{\emptyset,X, \{a\},\{c,d\}, \{a,c,d\}, \{b,c,d,e,f\}\}
$$
is a basis. Indeed, this is $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I was not aware that you are allowed intersections of the sets with themselves as well. :). This makes perfect sense then! :D.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm sorry for the earlier comment.

Comment: @user290425 , just out of interest. I know intersection of 0 elements is nullary, is there a similar notion for one element?

Comment: I've never heard the term "nullary" before, nor am I aware of a special word for the intersection of a collection containing only one element.